# AB class amplifier

Tags: amplifier, power-amplifier

[image]

In the class, we found the voltage Vceq2 as 2*Vbe+(R3+R4)*Io, where Io is current through resistors R3 and R4.

How are those two currents equal? Should there be a part that goes through Rp?

Comment: Not when the input is 0. The current that goes through R3 and R4 with no input signal is known as the quiescent current and it is used to bias the active components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no signal the amplifier should be biased such that both transistors conduct equally and the voltage at the junction of R3, R4, and Rp is zero wrt ground. On a positive going signal Q1 will conduct more and Q2 less, unbalancing the output causing current through Rp. On a negative going signal the reverse happens

In practice there will generally be a slight offset voltage at the output due to the transistors not being exact complements of each other. This will cause a current in Rp with no signal. This can be addressed by capacitively coupling Rp or adding an offset adjust circuit.

Comment: Just to add that the two transistors work simultaneously only in a narrow range of input voltage. Outside of it, only one of the two transistors remains to work; the other is off (it doesn't really need to keep working).